# Failure to display positive day Candlesticks using matplotlib.finance.candlestick2_ochl

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, finance, candlestick-chart

I have a python dataframe `df` containing Date, Open, High,Low, Close, and volume values.

I am attempting to Candlestick chart a stock. For some reason, I can't seem to get `matplotlib.finance.candlestick2_ochl()` to corectly display days where the stock price closed `self.df['closep']` was higher than stock price open `self.df['openp']`. On these positive (green) days, matplotlib either displays a doji or nothing at all.

Not quite sure why I am getting this behavior. I suspect it has something to do with the way my program is accessing the stock data from my Pandas DataFrame `self.df`.

Here is my code:

```
# Visualize my stock data

import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ochl
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


class MyStock:
    def __init__(self, stock):
        self.stock = stock
        self.pullData()


    def pullData(self):
        try:
            print('Currently pulling', self.stock)
            print(str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
            urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/' + self.stock + '/chartdata;type=quote;range=5d/csv'

            self.df = pd.read_csv(urlToVisit, header=None, names=['date', 'closep', 'highp', 'lowp', 'openp', 'volume'],
                             skiprows=22, dtype=float)

            print('Pulled', self.stock, '\n')

        except Exception as e:
            print('main loop', str(e))

        print('Constucting DataFrame\n')
        self.df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['date'], unit='s')

        self.df = self.df.set_index('date').tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern').reset_index()
        self.df['date'] = self.df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        print(self.df.tail())


    def CandleStick(self):


        self.fig = plt.figure()

        ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 4), (1, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=4, axisbg='w')

        candlestick2_ochl(ax1, opens=self.df['openp'], closes=self.df['closep'], highs=self.df['highp'], lows=self.df['lowp'], width=.75, colorup='k', colordown='r', alpha=0.75)

        plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
        ax1.grid(True)
        for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
            label.set_rotation(90)

        plt.subplots_adjust(left=.10, bottom=.19, right=.93, top=.95, wspace=.20, hspace=0)

        plt.suptitle(self.stock + ' Stock Price')
        plt.show()


amd = MyStock('AMD')
amd.CandleStick()
```

and a screenshot of the output alongside the associated section of the DataFrame:

[image]

You can clearly see in this screen cap that positive days (green) are not being displayed correctly. I am sure I'm missing something very obvious here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59670900/1639359

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this code that produces rightly colored candlesticks:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ochl
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


class MyStock:
    def __init__(self, stock):
        self.stock = stock
        self.pullData()


    def pullData(self):
        try:
            print('Currently pulling', self.stock)
            print(str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
            urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/' + self.stock + '/chartdata;type=quote;range=2d/csv'

            self.df = pd.read_csv(urlToVisit, header=None, names=['date', 'closep', 'highp', 'lowp', 'openp', 'volume'],
                             skiprows=22, dtype=float)

            print('Pulled', self.stock, '\n')

        except Exception as e:
            print('main loop', str(e))

        print('Constucting DataFrame\n')
        self.df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['date'], unit='s')

        self.df = self.df.set_index('date').tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern').reset_index()
        self.df['date'] = self.df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        print(self.df.tail())


    def CandleStick(self):


        self.fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 4), (1, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=4, axisbg='w')
        candlestick2_ochl(ax1,
                          self.df['openp'], self.df['highp'], self.df['lowp'], self.df['closep'],
                          width=.75, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha=0.75)

        plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
        ax1.grid(True)
        for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
            label.set_rotation(90)

        plt.subplots_adjust(left=.10, bottom=.19, right=.93, top=.95, wspace=.20, hspace=0)

        plt.suptitle(self.stock + ' Stock Price')
        plt.show()

amd = MyStock('AMD')
amd.CandleStick()
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

### a bug lies here

I'm using Matplotlib 1.5.1, there's a finance.py file in matplotlib directory, line 1059-1067. the original code is:

```
    candlestick2_ohlc(ax, opens, highs, closes, lows, width=width,
                 colorup=colorup, colordown=colordown,
                 alpha=alpha)


def candlestick2_ohlc(ax, opens, highs, lows, closes, width=4,
             colorup='k', colordown='r',
             alpha=0.75,
             ):
```

should be :

(exchange the places of 'closes' and 'lows' in parameters)

```
    candlestick2_ohlc(ax, opens, highs, lows, closes, width=width,
                 colorup=colorup, colordown=colordown,
                 alpha=alpha)


def candlestick2_ohlc(ax, opens, highs, lows, closes, width=4,
             colorup='k', colordown='r',
             alpha=0.75,
             ):
```

edit this file and save it. it should fix your problem.

> [Candlestick Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkh38.png).  sorry for no picture displayed here. you have
>   to click the url above to see the effect.

solved this problem within 2 hours (it's 2 a.m. now)
just the same way I guessed below 2 hours ago(but not excactly the same place), so sad that people voted me down.

---

### Something I wroted 2 hours ago.

I found this sentence in official Matplotlib API document, Chapter:"matplotlib.finance":

> Preserves the original argument order.

**Does this have anything to do with your problem?**

actually，i have got the same problem as you.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

candlestick(ax1,
        opens=test_data.open,
        closes=test_data.close,
        highs=test_data.high,
        lows=test_data.low,
        width=1,
        colorup='k',
        colordown='r',
        alpha=0.75)

fig.savefig('index.png',dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
```

and i got this:
[some wrong chart ploted by me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrDSI.png)

Comment: [link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/6869) this bug and it's fix has been officially accepted by Matplotlib.