# Since matplotlib.finance has been deprecated, how can I use the new mpl_finance module?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

I am trying to import `matplotlib.finance` module in python so that I can make a Candlestick OCHL graph. My `matplotlib.pyplot` version is 2.00. I've tried to import it using the following commands:

```
import matplotlib.finance
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
```

I get this error:

> warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
>   MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The finance module has been deprecated in mpl 2.0 and will be removed in mpl 2.2. Please use the module mpl_finance instead.

Then instead of using the above lines in python I tried using the following line:

```
import mpl_finance
```

I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named 'mpl_finance'

What should I do to import candlestick from `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What this warning tells you is that the finance module will be removed at some point.

At the moment you don't need to worry about this warning. It will only affect you when you update to a yet to be released version 2.2 of matplotlib, in which case you'll need to change your imports.

If you already want to be compatible with future versions now, you can download the `mpl_finance` module from
https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance .

After having downloaded the files, you may install in the usual way,

```
python setup.py install
```

Alternatively you may try installing through pip,

```
pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/archive/master.zip
```

The reason for this is that the people at matplotlib want to keep their code clean and not maintain a specialized sidepackage like this in the main code. They probably also do not want to maintain the package and spend resources on it, which can be better used in the core development.

Comment: Downloaded the zip file... How do i install it?

Comment: under normal conditions you need to install it using `python setup.py install`

Comment: mpl_finance no longer works. My guess is because 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv? ..' url is not working

Comment: @seedhom mpl_finance still works fine, but it can no longer be used to directly fetch data from Yahoo. One would need other datasources; still its plotting capabilities are unchanged.

Comment: after installing like you said, I now end up getting this error: ||NameError: name 'candlestick2_ohlc' is not defined||  I am using || import mpl_finance||, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 51):

I've stopped using mpl_finance (and plotly) since they are too slow. Instead I've written an optimized finance plotting library, [finplot](https://pypi.org/project/finplot/), which I use to backtest up to 10<sup>7</sup> candles.

Here's a small example:

```
import yfinance as yf
import finplot as fplt

df = yf.download('SPY',start='2018-01-01', end = '2020-04-29')
fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Open','Close','High','Low']])
fplt.plot(df.Close.rolling(50).mean())
fplt.plot(df.Close.rolling(200).mean())
fplt.show()
```

[Examples included](https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot/tree/master/finplot/examples) show SMA, EMA, Bollinger bands, Accumulation/Distribution, Heikin Ashi, on balance volume, RSI, TD sequential, MACD, scatter plot indicators, heat maps, histograms, real-time updating charts and interactive measurements; all with sensible defaults ready for use.

[image: MACD S&P 500 example]

I do dogfooding every day, drop me a note or a pull request if there is something you want. Hope you take it for a spin!

Comment: Really cool work dude! I have just tried and it goes smooth like a charm! Thumbs up

Comment: Wow this is EPIC. Been needing something like this for ages. Wish I was the OP so I could mark this as the answer!

Comment: Another very happy user here, nothing like it in Python ecosystem.

Comment: It's amazing. If there were some documentation it will be super useful. Thank you man

Comment: Could not install it unless using command pip install --user finplot. By doing that I got the error PyQt5 DLL load failed and Anaconda crashed. Cannot open it again

Comment: @Betelgeuse Strange, don't use conda myself. Did you figure it out? Do you know if pyqt5 works on your installation?

Comment: @Jonas Byström pyqt5 was working but I guess there was some conflicts after installing the package. I solved it by updating anaconda and uninstalling and installing again pyqt5.

Comment: Wonderful library, thanks! One thing that puts me off, why using OCHL instead of common OHLC in some function names?

Comment: @lenik Oops, total mistake on my part! I'll look into fixing that...

Comment: Legend, always wondered why there was so little financial charting options out there, you obviously took it personally. Great job.

Comment: @JonasByström, is this integrate-able with tkinter, as a tkinter widget, as matplotlib supports?

Comment: @Password-Classified Good question, for which I don't know the answer. You'd have to give it a shot.

Comment: @JonasByström it gives me the following error: 

`Sorry, "python" cannot be run on this version of macOS. Qt requires macOS 11.0.0 or later, you have macOS 10.15.7.`

Comment: @Volatil3 sounds like you need to install or upgrade python or your OS.

Answer (score 44):

In 2020, one can now `pip install mplfinance`

Comment: mpl_finance is deprecated.

pip install --upgrade mplfinance   (without the hypens)

Comment: Updated! Thanks for the heads up. Tis the season for quants :)

Comment: @duhaime Shouldn't it be `pip install mpl-finance` ?

Comment: @csg they're both on PyPi but `mplfinance` seems more maintained: https://pypi.org/search/?q=mplfinance+&o=

Answer (score 26):

Since `mpl_finace` is not on pip now, you may also want to use following command to install `mpl_finance` by `pip`:

`pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/archive/master.zip`

Comment: `mpl_finance` doesn't appear to be maintained any more, and it's started its way into oblivion and obsolescence, what should a honest newborn python developer use these days to plot candlesticks with some extra lines and graphics?

Answer (score 13):

`mpl_finance` is no longer part of `matplotlib`. Install the module directly from gitHub via pip

```
pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/archive/master.zip
```

and import it with

```
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
```

Then it works the same as before.

Answer (score 12):

**There is a new version of matplotlib finance, with documentation, here:**

- **https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/**
- **https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance**

Install with:   **`pip install --upgrade mplfinance`**

Or with:   **`conda install -c conda-forge mplfinance`**

**NOTE:** The package name no longer has the dash or underscore:
It is now **`mplfinance`** (*not* mpl-finance, nor mpl_finance)

Comment: `from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc` is how `candlestick_ohlc` is imported now.

Answer (score 6):

I'm working on google colab , i got the same problem . then what i did -for python3.6

`import mpl_finance`

`from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc`

Comment: After install using pip and before executing the sentences indicated above, I still have the same problem. Next I have done "conda list" and I see that "mpl_finance" are in the lista. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Plotly.py](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py), a web-browser based, interactive plotting module has finance plotting functions https://plot.ly/python/candlestick-charts/. And it is maintained.

Comment: Plotly is nice but is effectively only for web, does not work with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `pip install mpl_finance` for Windows or `pip3 install mpl_finance` for Linux/Unix for installation.

Then use `from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc` to call the library in the Jupyter notebook!

Answer (score 0):

Replace from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc with from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc , That should work.