# No module named 'matplotlib.finance', deprecated, and mpl_finance non maintained either

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a few candlesticks charts with additional lines and various graphics on the chart, but I found that `matplotlib.finance` has been deprecated. Replaced by `mpl_finance`, but that's unmaintained too.

What should a honest newborn python developer use these days to plot candlesticks? any ideas?

The code I would be going to use for this would be something like:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator,\
    DayLocator, MONDAY
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc

    mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)
    alldays = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
    weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d')  # e.g., Jan 12
    dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)
    # ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dayFormatter)

    #plot_day_summary(ax, quotes, ticksize=3)
    candlestick_ohlc(ax, candles, width=0.6)

    ax.xaxis_date()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(),
             rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `mpl_finance` without restriction. It's available at [github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42373582/4124317) on how to install it.

"Un-maintained" simply means that if you find a bug in it, noone will fix it for you.

Comment: It means also that in case of breaking changes to the underlying platforms the risk of being stuck is very high. But ok, I guess I have no choice. thanks

Comment: The code isn't very complicated. If it was to happen that an upstream package update breaks the code, you could always just copy the function from `mpl_finance` and fix it yourself.

Comment: @DonGiulio - it is now maintained, and there is a new version here: https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/

Answer (score 0):

@DonGiulio - it is now maintained, and there is a new version here: https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/