# Plot interval plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

I am trying to plot interval plots in python given the upper bound, lower bound, and point estimation. It should be like this.
[image]

For example, for the first line, I know the upper bound is 26, the lower bound is 24 and the point estimator is 25, so I can use these numbers to plot the line. I appreciate any advice. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373104/since-matplotlib-finance-has-been-deprecated-how-can-i-use-the-new-mpl-finance

Comment: `plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=1, ls='none')`.  Here `yerr` can be a single value (both upper and lower error), an array of N values (upper and lower error for all points) or a 2xN array with first all the lower errors and then all the upper errors. `yerr` is always a difference with the central value. See [`plt.errorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html).